# html5/javascript.Failed to insert data while using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Here is my code:

```
function set() {
    var db;
    var request;
    var store;

    var username = document.getElementById("username");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var newuser = {
        "username": username.value,
        "password": password.value,
    };
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;
    if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
        window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
        window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
    }

    request = indexedDB.open("userdb", 1);
    request.onerror = function(event) {};
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        db = event.target.result;
        var transaction = db.transaction(["user"], "readwrite");
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("user");
        var addrequest = objectStore.add(newuser);
        addrequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
            alert("Success");
        };
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        db = event.target.result;
        store = db.createObjectStore("user", {
            keyPath: "username",
            autoIncrement: false
        });
    };
}
```

After insert data,I use function get() to get data from indexedDB,but I failed to get that,What is the problem?Thank you!

```
function get() {
    var db;
    var request;
    var store;

    var username = document.getElementById("username");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;
    if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
        window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
        window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
    }

    request = indexedDB.open("userdb", 1);
    request.onerror = function(event) {
        alert("Error Code:" + event.target.errorCode);
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        db = event.target.result;
        var transaction = db.transaction("user", IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("user");
        objectStore.get(username.value);
        if (password.value == event.target.result.password)
            alert("Success“);
        else
            alert("Failed");
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        alert("Update Success");
    };
}
```

The function works after click another button to get data.But I failed to get data.I have added newuser(username:1 password:1) to the table user.But I cann't get the data.Why?Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually *does* work, though only once for a given username: after the record has been successfully added to the DB, it persists (which is the point in using IndexedDB in the first place), so subsequent attempts to execute `set()` result in a fail event on the `addrequest` object. This never shows up in your code as you haven't defined an `onerror` handler for said request.

Replace ...

```
addrequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    alert("Success");
};
```

...  with ...

```
addrequest.onerror = function(event) {
        if (console && console.log) { console.log("add op: Fail\n"); }
};
addrequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    if (console && console.log) { console.log("add op: Success\n"); }
};
```

... and see it happen (I've taken the liberty to replace alert with console output. Open the console by pressing ctrl-j in the browser window).

Tested on Chrome 50.

***Update***

Change the `get` function as follows:

Instead of ...

```
objectStore.get(username.value);
if (password.value == event.target.result.password)
    alert("Success“);
else
    alert("Failed");
```

... write ...

```
var getrequest = objectStore.get(newuser.username);
getrequest.onerror = function(event) {
        if (console && console.log) { console.log("get op: Fail\n"); }
};
getrequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    if (console && console.log) { console.log("get op: Success\n"); }
};
```

... and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.It really is helpful for me.But I have a new question.I can not get the data from indexeddb.Why?I have edited my question!Thanks.

Comment: It would work if you represented the request object for the `get` request in your code and attached the success/fail handlers to this object. I've adjusted the answer accordingly.